# System log error tab.phtml

Tags: tabs

I have the following error that keeps showing in the system log;
CRIT (2): Not valid template file:

`frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml`

There is no tabs.phtml file in the routing shown.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is one block that uses (tries to at least) the template `catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml`. And this one does not exist.

Most probably a block in the product view page.

Copy it from the `default/modern` theme to `base/default` or to your theme and it should be solved.

Comment: That worked, hooray, for once a clean system log. Thanks Marius

Comment: Please mark this answer as solution ig it solved your problem.